# Domain name, which one is more appropriate?

Tags: domains, name

I have 2 domains and want to start a hardware related website, but I want to make sure which one is the correct term in English:

1. `Hardwareden.com`
2. `HardwaresDen.com`

Please note the "S"!

Comment: You should ask this on [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 7):

Without the S. Hardware already refers to multiple, so there's no point in making it plural. Nobody in the United States says hardwares.

Comment: Indeed. Also, I'd advice buying the hyphenated version and (depending company size) misspelled domain variation for forwarding as well.